# Apagar valor do placeholder no input ao clicar utilizando AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Alguém sabe como posso apagar o valor do *placeholder* ao clicar no campo utilizando apenas AngularJS?

Exemplo: Ao clicar, some automaticamente a palavra nome.

```html
<input type="text" ng-model="inputText" placeholder="Nome" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Da seguinte forma:

```html
<input type="text" ng-model="inputText" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Nome'" placeholder="Nome" />
```

Comment: Obrigado Thiago

Answer (score 2):

Com [angular](/questions/tagged/angular), só lembrando que o comportamente normal o `input` oculta o `placeholder` quando há valor, mas, essa é uma forma de remover `placeholder` ao receber o `focus` e quando perde o foco é atribuído novamente o valor *Nome* no `placeholder`

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('ctrl', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {
    $scope.init = function() {
      var ele = angular.element("#input1")[0]
      ele.addEventListener('focus',
          function() {
              ele.setAttribute('placeholder', '');
          });
      ele.addEventListener('blur',
          function() {
              ele.setAttribute('placeholder', 'Nome');
          });
    }
    $scope.init();
  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <input type="text" id="input1" ng-init="inputText=''" ng-model="inputText" placeholder="Nome" />
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela explicação detalhada.